# Update ImageView through SharedPreference recreates activity?

Tags: java, android, xml

I've made an app where the user can change the image of the imageview to a different team logo through a ListPreference. It does change to the correct image when it's selected from the ListPreference, but when being ran on a device, it seems as if the whole activity gets recreated (ie, gets closed then reopened). Is there a way to avoid this so it's a smooth transition back to the MainActivity with the updated image without it looking like its being recreated.

Heres my code:

MainActivity:

```
     @Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    String team_chooser = getPrefs.getString("prefSetImage","1");

    if(team_chooser.equals("1")){
        awayTeam.setImageResource(R.drawable.team1logo);
    }else if(team_chooser.equals("2")){
        awayTeam.setImageResource(R.drawable.team2logo);
    }else if(team_chooser.equals("3")){
        awayTeam.setImageResource(R.drawable.team3logo);
    }
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.team_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.team_settings) {
        Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(settingsIntent);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

SettingsActivity:

```
        @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
    ActionBar actionBar = this.getSupportActionBar();

    if(actionBar != null){
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if(id == android.R.id.home){
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/team"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity"/>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

yes its,some time create problem so you just put the code in onResume().I hope it helps you.

Comment: Tried that. Unfortunately it still looks like it just recreates the whole activity again.